# If we have tab bar with a bunch of navigation controller, when a tab is selected, would the navigation controller pop back to bottom?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Because it seems to be what I am observing.

If I select the same tab again and again, for example, then the navigation controller seems to get popped out to bottom.

I wonder why.

I know that the UITabBarController displays the root view of the tab, which is the UINavigationTabController. But will the UINavigationTabController display it's rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

Its the way [`UITabBarController`s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) work:

> When the user selects a specific tab, the tab bar controller displays the root view of the corresponding view controller, replacing any previous views. (User taps always display the root view of the tab, regardless of which tab was previously selected. This is true even if the tab was already selected.)

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here. If in one of the tabs, I push to other controllers, then select another tab, and then come back to the first one, I see whatever controller I had last seen there, not the navigation controller's root view controller. So, I'm not sure how you're using the word "root".

Answer (score 0):

As @Rich points out, this is the default behavior. If you want to override it, though, you can implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate method -tabBarController:didSelectViewController: method and manipulate the UINavigationController for the selected tab to do what you want it to do.